# How to reset permissions in Windows 10 repair environment

Tags: windows, permissions

I can't boot into Windows 10.  I found the permissions are not correct.
I booted into the recovery environment.
I put this in a bat file:

```
c:
Icacls * /t /q /c /reset
```

and ran it as administrator.
In the command window.
What came back was:

```
C:\>Icacls * /t /q /c /reset
$RECYCLE.BIN: Access is denied.
$WINDOWS.~BT: Access is denied.
$WINDOWS.~LS: Access is denied.
$WinREAgent: Access is denied.
Batch: Access is denied.
boot: Access is denied.
Config.Msi: Access is denied.
Dnload: Access is denied.
Documents and Settings: Access is denied.
FRST: Access is denied.
Intel: Access is denied.
PerfLogs: Access is denied.
Program Files: Access is denied.
Program Files (x86): Access is denied.
ProgramData: Access is denied.
Programs: Access is denied.
QualityStats: Access is denied.
Recovery: Access is denied.
System Volume Information: Access is denied.
Temp: Access is denied.
Users: Access is denied.
Windows: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 13 files; Failed processing 44 files
```

All the folders and files have full permissions to these users and only these users:

```
S-1-5-21-347274278-327469549-447400862-500
S-1-5-21-347274278-327469549-447400862-1002
S-1-5-21-1955918374-137175358-2764517612-1000
```

I've been trying to figure out how to change the owner to my user and add full control to my user.

How can I fix the Access is denied so I can reset the Windows 10 permissions?

I would expect to see:

- Windows folder Owner TrustedInstaller
- Allow Trustratingly Full control
- Allow System Modify This folder only
- Allow System Full control Subfolders and files only
- Allow Administrators Modify This folder only
- Allow Administrators Full control Subfolders and files only
- Allow Users Read & execute
- Allow Creator Owner Full control
- Allow All Application Packages Read & execute
- Allow All Restricted Application Packages Read & execute

What I actually see for permissions Is:

```
Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-347274278-327469549-447400862-500) 
Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-347274278-327469549-447400862-1002) 
Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-1955918374-137175358-2764517612-1000)
```

All of the above folders have the same three permissions.

I don't know how to see the permissions within WinRE. I need to find a way to change the permissions so I can fix Windows 10. This PC is a dual boot. I also have a bootable USB drive where I can see the permissions from.

From Windows recovery I am getting Access Denied when trying to open C:\windows. What would you suggest?

How would you suggest I troubleshoot Windows 10 not booting up?

Comment: Some of those folders absolutely should not be owned by a user. Why do you believe changing the permissions on those folders will result in your system booting. I can guarantee that won’t be the case. If Windows cannot boot how did you determine which users have access to the folders and which user owns them?

Comment: Are you by chance determining the permissions within WinRE since your system obviously can't boot?

Comment: Those permissions absolutely would be expected due to you attempting to view the users of a Windows installation other than the Windows installation your viewing them on. **You cannot set the proper permissions of the Windows installation that doesn’t boot from another Windows installation.** Some of those folders absolutely should NOT be owned by a User on the system, Users folder for instance, if owned by a single User would prevent all logins from other users on the system. Program Files, ProgramData, are also vital folders that have their default permissions

Comment: If you have info to add, please don't do it in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771660/edit) your question as I now did for you. This way the relevant info is readily available. As I moved all your comments to the question. I'd suggest deleting the ones here to leave space for other members of the community.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reset permissions, first you must have the appropriate rights to make changes to the permissions. To do this you have to run this command first:

```
takeown /R /F *.
```

Afterwards, you can run the command you've been trying unsuccessfully.

Also, you can check this article: [Restore or Reset NTFS Permissions in Windows 10 Effectively (5 Ways)](https://www.ubackup.com/backup-restore/restore-ntfs-permissions-3889.html)